# Python Spark group transactions into nested schema

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to group the transactions stored in a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` "`ddf`" by a column "`key`" that indicates the source of the transaction (in this case customer ID).

The grouping is quite an expensive process so I want to write the groups to disk in a nested schema:

```
(key, [[c1, c2, c3,...], ...])
```

This will allow me to load all the transactions on a key quickly, and develop the complex custom aggregators without re-running the grouping.

How do I create a nested schema and write it to disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me quite a while to figure this out, though the answer turns out to be simple, so I thought I'd post my solution here.

First reduce all the transactions by `key` (customer ID):

```
from operators import add
# ddf is a dataframe with a transaction in each row.  Key is the column
# we want to group the transactions by.

txnrdd = ddf.rdd.map(lambda row: (row['key'], [row],) ).reduceByKey(add)
```

This gives an `rdd` that looks like `(key, [list of Rows])`.  To write this back into a `dataframe` you need to build the schema.  The transaction lists can be modelled by `ArrayType`.

```
from pyspark.sql import types as sqxt
txn_schema = sqxt.StructType([
    sqxt.StructField('Key', sqxt.StringType()),
    sqxt.StructField('Transactions', sqxt.ArrayType(ddf.schema))
])
```

Then it's straightforward to write the data to disk in this structure:

```
txnddf = txnrdd.toDF(schema=txn_schema)
txnddf.write.parquet('customer-transactions.parquet')
```

Performance seems OK.  Couldn't find a way to do this without going via an RDD.